# Running a Java program from a different directory

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to run a Java program from a different directory.
I tried following command:
`java -cp /home/<username>/<program>/<libraries>/* -Program-`

The issue is that the program writes a file that is now not written in the directory `<program>` but in the directory it was started from.

How would i have to adjust my code to accomplish this?

Comment: To solve this "problem", ask yourself where you want to write mentioned file. If it's "current working directory" then it's working as expected...

Comment: You are of course right. I am sorry. I just could not think of changing the directory in the code itself.